# xWalkWebView 64bit is not supported for many devices when I publish app on Google Play after changes from Google

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Google dont want allow apps with 32 bit native libraries so I replaced:

```
implementation 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
```

with xwalk library 64bit, but it doesn't support a lot of devices (30%), how to make this library to work at 32 bit and 64 also?
Thanks.

I tried to use 64 bit library but it doesn't support a lot of devices

```
implementation 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
```

Comment: how did you upgrade it to 64bit version? Did you included a jar?

Comment: Yes, I included jar file.

Comment: Can you please mention the steps and file link for 64bit jar? Also, are you able to upload it on Playstore 64bit version?